# I can't run server via "python manage.py runserver"

Tags: python, django, macos, terminal, virtualenv

I want to run my virtual env. via "python manage.py runserver" but always get this message:

```
"RuntimeError: __class__ not set defining 'AbstractBaseUser' as <class 'django.contrib.auth.base_user.abstractbaseuser'="">. Was __classcell__ propagated to type.__new__?"
```

Does anyone know what causes this problem?

I'm using Django 1.10 and Python 3.5.8

Thanks in advance,
Chris

Comment: did you "activate" your virtual environment?  Something like `$ source env/bin/activate`

Comment: Yes, have done that!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Provide \_\_classcell\_\_ example for Python 3.6 metaclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41343263/provide-classcell-example-for-python-3-6-metaclass)

Comment: @ChristopherWippel where did you placed your `virtual environment` folder? Are you activating it on the right place?

Comment: @EliasPrado its on my Desktop. This worked in the past just fine. The link provided above does not help with my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach I have added in this post and see whether it works or not.

[Trying to install django to my virtual env](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60743351/trying-to-install-django-to-my-virtual-env/60743612#60743612)

Comment: Hi, this is exactly how i did it, but did not work. Today i tried it with Python 3.7 and it worked fine. I will go with that solution for now. But thank you for your support.

Comment: which solution?

Comment: It looks like the problem only appears by using python 3.5.8 so i upgraded to 3.7 and it works. I haven't found out why i got the error with V 3.5 but so don't have found a solution for this particular problem.